# Skip License/Credit Comments when minifying JavaScript using YUIcompressor

Tags: javascript, comments, minify, yui-compressor

Is there a way to keep license/credit comments when the JavaScript is being minified by YUICompressor? Is there any special commenting characters? Or any flag for that in YUICompressor?

Thanks,
Grace

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, use

```
/*!
 *
 */
```

The exclamation tells the compressor to retain the comment.

[Documentation](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/README.md#notes)

Comment: I opened the YUI documentation page before Stackoverflow and decided to ake a quick peek at Stackoverflow first, as the question looked exctly what I needed. As usual I didn't need to go anywhere else :)