# Strange comment syntax javascript. Forward slash star exclamation mark

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to do some stuff but came across a strange comment syntax. Forward slash star exclamation mark.

```
/*!
```

Dose it have a special meaning, do anything, or what does it represent?

One example is:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: Tue Nov 13 2012 08:20:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
 */
```

Comment: It was in regards to a minifier this occurred. Seems relevant to metion ;P

Comment: a.k.a. "forward slash star bang"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `/*!` tells the JavaScript minifier to not remove the comment. This is important for license information that has to stay in the file. See [Skip License/Credit Comments when minifying JavaScript using YUIcompressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614532/skip-license-credit-comments-when-minifying-javascript-using-yuicompressor)

Comment: Today I learned... However, since that's a YUIcompressor functionality, I'd suggest mentioning it has no meaning as far as the JavaScript standard is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the `!` doesn't mean anything in there, as far as the JavaScript standard is concerned.

It's just a basic comment block with some eye candy. Like this, in it's basic form:

```
/*
*/
```

**However**, as erjiang [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21832804/1835379), it has meaning for some minifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This is used with [uglify](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs). If you use `/*!` uglify won't remove the comment. You can also use [`@preserve`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#keeping-copyright-notices-or-other-comments).